# Using of list to search for string name and by index with large amount of values

Tags: c#, arrays, list, dictionary, hashset

What is the proper, more fast and accurate way to search for specific value by name and index into the large set of string values, about 7000 items in updated but unaltered sequence order.

I want avoid using of data base by several reasons in my case, but include it in the list for comparisons maybe also has a point.

1)

```
List<string> List = new List<string>();
```

I checked list values for 90 000 values to replace if string contains any of exist, seems like it is faster then  `ISet<String> List = new HashSet<String>();` and `HashSet<string>` with `ElapsedMilliseconds` results.

Not sure if this checking is enough to say for sure, but result by exist value from string with replacing is fast, accurate and never average or slow in comparing with `ISet` and `HashSet`, even if `ISet` and `HashSet`  advantage to each other depends on amount like e.g 20000 or 90000 values. In this kind of search seems like `List<string>` is always faster, and results mostly looks like this:

```
List:  312 ems (fast)
ISet: 514 ems (average) 
HashSet: 563 ems (slow)
```

also just to check I tried find difference in speed and accuracy of implementation between search in list and search in text document indexed by list range, seems like result is same.

Anyway, I'm not sure if it is desirable for large lists, and as I understand, search by string or index is not the same as replacing.

2)

```
HashSet<string> hashSetStr = new HashSet<string>();
```

Works fast for formation, but how it works with direct using if I need both search by name and by index into the list of items which must be related to each other in unchanged order.

3)

```
Dictionary<string, int> Dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Pair integer which can be used as index and string value, but how search is related on amount of values with updated Dictionary

Comment: if your list can be sorted, the function `Array.BinarySearch`might be an option for you

Comment: Everything you need should be in [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx) article.

Comment: Since you need index search, you cannot use ***ISet*** - ***HashSet*** and ***SortedSet***. For both name and index search, you might want to look at ***SortedDictionary*** *O(log n)* if names are unique.

Comment: @ CodingYoshi  thank you, very useful article